Compactly generated and paracompact $\Rightarrow$ Hausdorff?
In A Concise Course in Algebraic Topology by May, a proposition is stated that any open cover of a paracompact space has a numerable refinement, where the space is assumed to be compactly generated due to his standing hypothesis. But I don't know what's the exact meaning of the word "paracompact" here.
I understand that a paracompact space is typically defined as a topological space in which every open cover has a locally finite refinement. However, some authors additionally use the term “paracompact” to imply the space is also Hausdorff. In other words, these authors use “paracompact space” to refer to a space that is both Hausdorff and paracompact in the usual sense. It is unclear if May requires a paracompact space to be Hausdorff.
Here's some notation from the book:

A $k$-space $X$ is a space in which a subspace $U\subset X$ is closed if and only if the preimage $t ^{-1}(U)$ under any continuous function $t:C\longrightarrow X$ out of a compact Hausdorff space $C$ is closed.
A space $X$ is said to be weak Hausdorff if the image of a continuous function $f:C\longrightarrow X$ out of a compact Hausdorff space $C$ is closed. This separation property lies between $T _{1}$ (points are closed) and Hausdorff, but it is not much weaker than the latter.
A compactly generated space $X$ is a weak Hausdorff $k$-space.
An open cover $\mathscr{O}$ of a space $X$ is numerable if it's locally finite and for every $U\in \mathscr{O}$ there's a continuous function $\lambda _{U}:X\longrightarrow I=[0,1]$ such that $\lambda _{U}^{-1}(0,1]=U$.

If the term “paracompact” in the book also carries the additional meaning of being Hausdorff, then it’s easy to prove the proposition by partition of unity.
But I don't know if the proposition holds for spaces that are compactly generated, paracompact but not Hausdorff. It’s true if and only if compactly generated and paracompact $\Rightarrow$ Hausdorff: indeed, assume that every open cover of a $T _{1}$ space $X$ has a numerable refinement, and $a\ne b$ are points of $X$, typically $\left \{ X\setminus {\left \{ a\right \}} ,X\setminus {\left \{ b\right \}}\right \}$ has a numerable refinement $\mathscr{O}$. Assume that $a\in U\in \mathscr{O}$, the open set $\left \{ \lambda _{U}(x)>\lambda _{U}(a)/2\right \}$ and the open set $\left \{ \lambda _{U}(x)<\lambda _{U}(a)/2\right \}$ are seperated. So $X$ is Hausdorff.
So the question is :
Must a compactly generated and paracompact space be Hausdorff ?

This question is not about research mathematics.  Looks like it would be more appropriate for https://math.stackexchange.com/

The one-point compactification of the rationals is a Fréchet-Urysohn space, each of whose compact subsets is closed. In particular, it is compactly generated. It is compact, so paracompact by your definition. But it is not Hausdorff.

Questions like these are easily answered with a search of pi-Base:
π-Base, Search for $k_3$-space+Paracompact+~$T_2$
Six counterexamples are listed there today, including Tyrone's example. I'll suggest $\omega_1+1$ with the endpoint doubled (S37) as another. It is compact and therefore paracompact. It is compactly generated because each point has a compact Hausdorff neighborhood.
In fact, this is a general construction: take your favorite paracompact Hausdorff locally compact space, then double a non-isolated point.
